# Border-radius will not work in IE9

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a website and my container box has rounded corners, the rounded corners will work in all other browsers except IE9. Here is the link to my website: http://www.canadiannaturephotographer.com/~teacher/Kelsey/index.html
and here is the html code:

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
<html lang="en">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="description" content="Kelsey's fishing site provides information on locations to fish, fishing equipment, and fish trophies.">
<meta name="keywords" content="fishing, site, net, bait, catch, release, trophy, fish, guide, locations, location, best, educational, tutor, instruction, equip, equipment, contact, feedback, about, how, to, fishing rod, rod, fly, fly-fish, fly fishing, hook, angler, angle, angling, fishes, wire, product, electronic, gps, navigation, vest, beer, pike, salmon, wall-eye, whitefish, white fish, trout, rainbow, herring, mountain, nature, valley, river, lake, ocean, shore, coast, dock, fly fish, worm, maggot, dry, ice, season, winter, fall, summer, spring, price, best, spot, to, go, calgary, alberta, canada, north america, travel, boat, motor, buoyancy, float, floaty, bobber, bob, bobbing, weight, reel, reeling, in, big, giant, huge, massive, large, aquatic, life, aqua, water, sand, tackle, tackle box, box, live, insects, insect, hunt, outdoors, outdoorsman, wildlife, food, cook, wild, out,"> 
<title>About ~ Kelsey's Fishing Site</title>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Scada' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='cssfishsite.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link rel="icon" type="image/ico" href="images/faviconn.ico">
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">

<header><center><img src="images/fishing-banner.jpg" class="topround"></center></header>

<nav>
<ul>
<li><a class="navbarr" href="index.html">About</a></li>
<li><a class="navbarr" href="fishingtrophies.html">Trophies</a></li>
<li><a class="navbarr" href="fishinglocations.html">Locations</a></li>
<li><a class="navbarr" href="fishingequipment.html">Equipment</a></li>
<li><a class="navbarr" href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
<li><a class="navbarr" href="feedback.html">Feedback</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>

<article>
<img id="trophyp" src="images/trophypike.jpg" width="200" height="340" alt="Very large trophy pike" title="Massive trophy pike" align="left"><p id="mainpagetitle">Featured Trophy Fish</p>
<p class="paratag"><span class="description1">Length:</span> 56"</p>
<p class="paratag"><span class="description1">Weight:</span> 55 lb</p>
<p class="paratag"><span class="description1">Location:</span> Turtle Lake, Saskatchewan</p>
<p class="paratag"><span class="description1">Story:</span> This fish was caught in the open waters of Turtle lake when the fisherman caught a 36" Pike. As he was reeling the pike in, the 50 lb pike tried to eat it! The fisherman caught them both in the same net. <br /><br />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Wow!!</p>
<br />

</article>
<br /><br />
<br />
<hr />
<br />
<div id="box32"><img id="trophyp2" src="images/E-_Kelsey'sfishingsite_images_2110612-636818-fresh-bright-trout-fish-isolated-on-a-white-background.gif" width="240" height="160.5" alt="bright trout fish" title="Fresh Bright Trout" align="right"><p><div id="textbox2"><span class="darkblue">Welcome!</span><span class="fonteh"> This website has been created to educate user's on fishing locations within Alberta, what fishing gear to utilize, etc. This website also allows users to post their trophy fish with a chance to be featured on the homepage. I hope you enjoy the website and please send feedback!</span></p></div></div>
<br />

<br />
<hr />
<p id="thirdpagetitle">Submit Your Trophy Fish!</p>
<form method="post" action="trophyfishsubmit.php" align="center">
<fieldset style="padding: 10px;" bgcolor="white"><div class="whiteformbox"><br />
<center>Name: <br /><input type="text" name="name" id="name"> <br /><blockquote></blockquote>
Location: <br /><input type="text" name="location" id="location"><br /><blockquote></blockquote>
Fish: <br /><blockquote></blockquote>
<input type="text" name="fish" id="fish">
<br />
<p>Story: </p>
<textarea cols="50" rows="9" name="story"></textarea><br />
<p>Please send your photos to my E-mail at: <br /><br />
<a href="mailto:k.nealon@hotmail.com">K.nealon@hotmail.com</a></p>
<br />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send">
<p><strong><font size="2">Privacy Policy:</strong> All information gathered in this form will be kept strictly confidential and will not be exploited in any way.</font></p></center><div></fieldset>
</form>
<br />
<br /><br />



<footer><p align="center">Last Updated October 4th, 2013 ~ Calgary, Alberta</p></footer>

</div><!-- this is the container end div tag -->
<br />
<center><font face="verdana"><a class="sitemap" href="sitemap.html">Sitemap</a></font></center>
</body>
</html>
```

Now here is the CSS:

```
#container {
    width: 761px;
    background-color: beige;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin: 0 auto;
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, Sans-serif;
}

body {
    background-color: white;
    background-image: url("images/clouds.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: top;
}

.description1 {
    color: #2caeec;
}

.paratag2 {
    padding-left: 180px;
    width: 410px;
}

.paratag {
    padding-left: 280px;
}

nav {
    font-style: bold;
    font-size: 0.8em;
    background-color: #b1b1b1;
    color: red;
    margin-right: 0.07px;
    margin-top: -3px;
}

#box32 {
    width: 750px;
}

#textbox2 {
    width: 400px;
    padding-left: 50px;
    height: 150px;
}

.darkblue {
    color: darkblue;
}

.fonteh {
    color: #2caeec;
}

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

li {
    float: left;
}

.header1s {
    color: #2caeec;
}

.boxie {
    border: 10px solid black;
    border-radius: 5px;
    width: 300px;
    height: 260px;
}

.stang {
    color: #2caeec;
}

#information1 {
    width: 430px;
    margin: auto;
}

#information24 {
    width: 600px;
    margin: auto;
    color: #2caeec;
    font-size: 1.1em;
}

#mainpagetitle {
    font-family: 'Scada', sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 3.0em;
    color: #2caeec;
    padding-left: 270px;
}

#mainpagetitle2 {
    font-family: 'Scada', sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 3.0em;
    color: #2caeec;
    padding-left: 365px;
}

#sitemap1 {
    font-family: 'Scada', sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 3.0em;
    color: #2caeec;
}

#thirdpagetitle {
    font-family: 'Scada', sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 3.0em;
    color: #2caeec;
    padding-left: 100px;
}

#thirdpagetitle1 {
    font-family: 'Scada', sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 3.0em;
    color: #2caeec;
}

a.navbarr:link {
    display: block;
    width: 122.6666666666697px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: beige;
    background-color: #2caeec;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 1px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    border: 1px outset gray;
    border-radius: 5px;
}   /* border optional */ 

a.navbarr:visited {
    display: block;
    width: 122.6666666666667px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: beige;
    background-color: #2caeec;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 1px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    border: 1px outset gray;
}

a.navbarr:hover {
    display: block;
    width: 122.6666666666667px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: beige;
    background-color: #b1b1b1;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 1px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    border: 1px outset gray;
}   /* border optional */ 

a.navbarr:active {
    background-color: #b1b1b1;
    color: beige;
}

a.sitemap:link {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #2caeec;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 1px;
    text-decoration: none;
}   /* border optional */ 

a.sitemap:visited {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #2caeec;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 1px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

a.sitemap:hover {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #b1b1b1;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 1px;
    text-decoration: none;
}   /* border optional */ 

a.sitemap:active {
    color: #b1b1b1;
}

article {
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-top: 30px;
}

header {
    padding-bottom: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

footer {
    background-color: #2caeec;
    color: beige;
    border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;
    margin-bottom: -20px;
}

.padding {
    padding: 10px;
}

form {
    margin-bottom: -16px;
}

fieldset {
    width: 500px;
    margin: auto;
}

.clearfloat {
    clear: both;
}

.topround {
    border-radius: 10px 10px 0px 0px;
}

p {
    font-family: arial;
    font-size: 1em;
    padding-left: 30px;
    padding-right: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

#feedbackhead {
    font-family: 'Pinyon Script', cursive;
    margin: auto;
    font-size: 3.0em;
    color: #2caeec;
}

.fsSubmitButton {
    border-top: 2px solid #a3ceda;
    border-left: 2px solid #a3ceda;
    border-right: 2px solid #4f6267;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #4f6267;
    padding: 10px 20px !important;
    font-size: 14px !important;
    background-color: #2caeec;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: beige;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.fsSubmitButton:hover {
    border-top: 2px solid #a3ceda;
    border-left: 2px solid #a3ceda;
    border-right: 2px solid #4f6267;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #4f6267;
    padding: 10px 20px !important;
    font-size: 14px !important;
    background-color: beige;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #2caeec;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#trophyp2 {
    padding-right: 50px;
    positon: absolute;
    bottom: 555px;
}

#trophyp {
    padding-left: 35px;
}

#trophyd {
    padding-left: 25px;
}

#trophyp32 {
    padding-left: 35px;
}
```

PS: The banner has a slight space between the container border and the banner picture, wondering how I could fix that?

Comment: Make sure you've applied an html5 doctype to your page `<!DOCTYPE html>` that could be your problem

Comment: Hi, I've viewed your link with both IE9 and Chrome - under win7. The page is identical in both browsers - the corners are just fine. Do you have extensions/plugins installed?

Comment: How would I check if I have extensions/plugins? I don't think so...

Comment: @Kelseey - you can check via the menu: `Tool->Manage add-ons` I've got a bunch of them myself, apparently. I think Blake's suggestion further on down this page that Compatibility Mode is the culprit seems fairly likely. A different icon is shown somewhere (I forget where, google will know) on the browser to indicate compatibility mode has been employed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix the sequence in your HTML opening sequence, it should be

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
```

But as far as I know (and I'm not a browser expert) there actually *are* isues with IE and border-radius.

In case your IE actually switches to compatibility mode you can inhibit this by transmitting this response header:

```
header('X-UA-Compatible: IE=edge');
```

Note that this MUST be done server side, a META header will be of no use in this case as it comes too late.

Comment: Isn't `lang="en"` depreciated in HTML5? Wouldn't you just define a `charset` in the `head`? `<meta charset='UTF-8'>`

Comment: @JoshC - no, "lang" is a global attribute that in theory can be applied everywhere (see http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_lang.asp).

Comment: @Kelseey there's a good chance your IE has been kicked into compatibility mode, which is known to cause all sorts of problems.

Comment: @macke is quite right, and IE most often switches to compatibility mode in intranets. See the edit to my answer.

Comment: @ErnestV where would I put the "header('X-UA-Compatible: IE=edge');" in my html code? thank you!